# Reading from/Writing to Byte Arrays in C# .net 4

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer, memory-mapped-files

Greetings Overflowers,

I love the flexibility of memory mapped files in that you can read/write any value type.
Is there a way to do the same with byte arrays without having to copy them into for e.g. a memory map buffers ?

Regards

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `BitConverter` class to convert between base data types and byte arrays.

You can read values directly from the array:

```
int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, pos);
```

To write data you convert it to a byte array, and copy it into the data:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(value).CopyTo(data, pos);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to a given byte array, set it's property `Position` to go to a specific position within the array, and then use a [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) or [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) to read / write values of different types from/to it.

Comment: thx man! Although named stream, it allows random access. Is there a way to read/write array of values using BinaryReader/Writer ? Appreciated.

Comment: @geeko: you are just one click away from the API docs, there are methods for reading/writing arrays of characters and bytes. If you want to other value types, just use a loop.

Comment: thx again. I read the docs before. It seems that Buffer.BlockCopy and BitConvertor the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching the [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) class which can be initialised (without copying!) from a fixed-size byte array.

Answer (score 0):

(Using unsafe code)
The following sample shows how to fill a 16 byte array with two long values, which is something BitConverter still can't do without an additional copy operation:

```
byte[] bar = new byte[16];
long lValue1 = 1;
long lValue2 = 2;
unsafe {
    fixed (byte* bptr = &bar[0]) {
        long* lptr = (long*)bptr;
        *lptr = lValue1;
        // pointer arithmetic: for a long* pointer '+1' adds 8 bytes.
        *(lptr + 1) = lValue2;
    }
}
```

Or you could make your own StoreBytes() method:

```
// here the dest offset is in bytes
public static void StoreBytes(long lValue, byte[] dest, int iDestOffset) {
    unsafe {
        fixed (byte* bptr = &dest[iDestOffset]) {
            long* lptr = (long*)bptr;
            *lptr = lValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Reading values from a byte array is no problem with BitConverter since you can specify the offset in .ToInt64.

Alternative : use Buffer.BlockCopy, which can convert between array types.